# Service Fabric Stateful Service failing - requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast

Tags: azure-service-fabric

A service fabric application that we've been running in a cluster without issues has recently moved to an "error" state.

My colleague raised a similar issue in [this SO article][1], which was supposedly fixed with Service Fabric version 5.3.311

However, our Service Fabric version is now at 5.5.216.0
Note: Our code is deleting and recreating the state rapidly rather than adding / removing keys from it.

The service is a Reliable Stateful Service, with 1 partition and 3 replicas (i.e., one primary, two secondary). The service implements a long-running RunAsync(), and reads and writes to/from many ReliableDictionary entries concurrently during RunAsync().

We have noticed the following error in the event log on the primary node:

```
Application: RPFabric.Service.Tenant.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Lsn obtained through replication is 634711 and metadata present in deleted state is Name: urn:<StateName>, StateProviderId: 131414644208509332, CreateLSN: 634679, DeleteLSN: 634695 MetadataMode: DelayDelete TransactionId: 0
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.Utility.Assert(Boolean, System.String, ...)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<ApplyOnRecoveryAsync>d__89.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<ApplyOnRecoveryAsync>d__89, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ApplyOnRecoveryAsync>d__89 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.ApplyOnRecoveryAsync(Int64, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionBase, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ReplicationMetadata)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyOnLocalStateAsync>d__f6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyOnLocalStateAsync>d__f6, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<OnApplyOnLocalStateAsync>d__f6 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.OnApplyOnLocalStateAsync(Int64, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionBase, System.Fabric.OperationData, System.Fabric.OperationData, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ApplyContext)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyAsync>d__4c.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyAsync>d__4c, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<OnApplyAsync>d__4c ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.OnApplyAsync(Int64, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionBase, System.Fabric.OperationData, System.Fabric.OperationData, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ApplyContext, Int64)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyAsync>d__47, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<OnApplyAsync>d__47 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.OnApplyAsync(Int64, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionBase, System.Fabric.OperationData, System.Fabric.OperationData, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ApplyContext)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator+<ApplyCallback>d__ce.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator+<ApplyCallback>d__ce, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ApplyCallback>d__ce ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator.ApplyCallback(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecord)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator+<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ILogRecordsProcessor.ProcessLoggedRecordAsync>d__ab.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator+<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ILogRecordsProcessor.ProcessLoggedRecordAsync>d__ab, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ILogRecordsProcessor.ProcessLoggedRecordAsync>d__ab ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ILogRecordsProcessor.ProcessLoggedRecordAsync(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecord)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<ProcessTransaction>d__1f.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<ProcessTransaction>d__1f, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ProcessTransaction>d__1f ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher.ProcessTransaction(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionLogRecord>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<SeparateTransactions>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<SeparateTransactions>d__24, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<SeparateTransactions>d__24 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher.SeparateTransactions()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<ProcessLoggedRecords>d__a.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(Int32)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(Int32)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<SeparateTransactions>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecordsDispatcher+<ProcessTransaction>d__1f.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator+<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ILogRecordsProcessor.ProcessLoggedRecordAsync>d__ab.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator+<ApplyCallback>d__ce.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyAsync>d__4c.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<OnApplyOnLocalStateAsync>d__f6.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager+<ApplyOnRecoveryAsync>d__89.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5+<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.IStateProvider2.RecoverCheckpointAsync>d__f3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at System.Fabric.Store.MetadataManager+<WriteAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at System.Fabric.Store.MetadataManager+<WriteAsync>d__2c.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```